# How to get values from array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object from which I am trying to get values using map operator but I am getting the whole json objects all I want is just array of values.
Below is my code:

```
const obj = [
             {
              a: {
                  b: 'Paul',
                 }
             },
              {  
                c: 'Byeeee',
              }
           ];

obj.map((val) => console.log(val));
```

what I am getting is

```
{ a: { b: 'Paul' } }
{ c: 'Byeeee' }
```

What I want is:

```
['Paul','Byeeee']
```

Someone let me know how can I get the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this recursively. You can first start off by grabbing the values of your object, and then loop through those using `.flatMap()`. If you encounter a value that is an object, you can recursively grab the values of that object by recalling your function. Otherwise, you can return the value. The advantage of using `.flatMap()` here is that when the recursive call returns an array, we don't end up with inner arrays, but rather the array gets flattened into one resulting array:

```js
const obj = [{ a: { b: 'Paul', } }, { c: 'Byeeee', } ];

const getValues = (obj) => {
  return Object.values(obj).flatMap(val => Object(val) === val ? getValues(val) : val);
}
console.log(getValues(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following solution.

```
  const data = [{ a: { b: 'Paul' } }, { c: 'Byeeee' }];

  const flatObjectValues = (obj, result) => {
  // recursive function to get object values
  const objValues = Object.values(obj);
  if (objValues?.length > 0) {
    objValues.map((v) => {
      if (typeof v === 'object' && !Array.isArray(v)) {
        flatObjectValues(v, result);
      } else {
        result.push(v);
      }
      return v;
    });
  }
};

const updatedData = [];
data.map((x) => flatObjectValues(x, updatedData));
console.log('updatedData: ', updatedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `recursion` with `array.reduce`, like fellowing.

```js
function getAllValues(objuct) {
  return objuct.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (typeof curr === 'object') {
      return [...acc, ...getAllValues(Object.values(curr))];
    }
    return [...acc, curr];
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution could be:

```js
const arr = [{a: {b: "Paul",},},{c: "Byeeee",},];

const flatArrOfObjects = (arr) => {
    const values = [];
    for (const i in arr) flatObj(arr[i], values);
    return values;
};

const flatObj = (obj, result) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (typeof value === "object") flatObj(value, result);
        else result.push(value);
    }
};

console.log(flatArrOfObjects(arr));
```